# Unique cumulative customers by each day

Tags: sql, hive, count, hiveql, window-functions

Task: Get the total number of unique cumulative customers by each decline reason and by each day.

```
    Input data sample:
    +---------+--------------+------------+------+
    | Cust_Id |  Decline_Dt  |  Reason    | Days |
    +---------+--------------+------------+------+
    |   A     |  08-09-2020  |  Reason_1  |   0  |
    |   A     |  08-09-2020  |  Reason_1  |   1  | 
    |   A     |  08-09-2020  |  Reason_1  |   2  |
    |   A     |  08-09-2020  |  Reason_1  |   4  |
    |   B     |  08-09-2020  |  Reason_1  |   0  |
    |   B     |  08-09-2020  |  Reason_1  |   2  |
    |   B     |  08-09-2020  |  Reason_1  |   3  |
    |   C     |  08-09-2020  |  Reason_1  |   1  |
    +---------+--------------+------------+------+   
1) Decline_dt - The date on which the payment was declined. (Ignore it for this task)
2) Days - Indicates the # of days after the payment decline happened, the customer interacted with IVR channel. 
3) Reason - Indicates the payment decline reason 
    
    --Expected Output:
    +---------------+-----------+---------------+----------------------------+
    |   Reason      |   Days    | Unique_mtns   | total_cumulative_customers |
    +---------------+-----------+---------------+----------------------------+
    |   Reason_1    |   0       |   2           |           2                |              
    |   Reason_1    |   1       |   2           |           3                |
    |   Reason_1    |   2       |   2           |           3                | 
    |   Reason_1    |   3       |   1           |           3                | 
    |   Reason_1    |   4       |   1           |           3                | 
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My Hive query:

```
select a.Reason
        , a.days
        -- , count(distinct a.cust_id) as unique_mtns
        , count(distinct a.cust_id) over (partition by Reason 
                                                order by a.days rows between unbounded preceding and current row) 
                                        as total_cumulative_customers
from table as a  
group by a.reason
        , a.days
```

Output (Incorrect):

```
+---------------+-----------+----------------------------+
|   Reason      |   Days    | total_cumulative_customers |
+---------------+-----------+----------------------------+
|   Reason_1    |   0       |               2            |              
|   Reason_1    |   1       |               2            |
|   Reason_1    |   2       |               2            | 
|   Reason_1    |   3       |               1            | 
|   Reason_1    |   4       |               1            | 
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Ideally, I would expect the window function to be executed without group by.
However, I get an error without group by. When I use group by, I don't get the cumulative customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use a subquery to compute the first day per customer/reason tuple, and then do conditional aggregation:

```
select reason, days, 
    count(distinct cust_id) as unique_mtns,
    sum(sum(case when days = min_days then 1 else 0 end)) 
        over(partition by reason order by days) as total_cumulative_customers
from (
    select reason, cust_id, 
        min(days) over(partition by reason, cust_id) as min_days
    from mytable
) t
group by reason, days
```

Comment: Some columns are unavailable in outer query. Also `min_days` is not present in group by, so there should be another `sum` or it should throw an error (maybe in Hive it works differently?). This can be fixed by marking first day in inner query with `lag(0, 1, 1) over(partition by reason, cust_id order by days asc)`

Comment: Thank you @GMB! Your solution works fine after the edit made by you by adding another sum. Thank you @astentx, by adding another sum, I got the query running.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `row_number()` to enumerate the rows or a given customer and reason.  Your code uses `count(distinct)` on the user id, suggesting that you might have duplicates on a given day.

This would be:

```
select reason, days, count(distinct cust_id) as unique_mtns,
       sum(sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) over (partition by reason order by days) as total_cumulative_customers
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by reason, cust_id order by days) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by reason, days
order by reason, days;
```

Comment: I do not have duplicates on a given day. count(*) gives me the same result. Anyway, your solution works as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Ashish . . . Your question uses `count(distinct)` giving the impression that your data has such duplicates.